# LN: Use value as color view column property, apply colors only to defined columns

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

In lotus notes 6.5 i'm trying to use colors to put in evidence some data using "use value as color" view column property and put this formula: **@If(CallType="Incoming";0:0:255;255:0:0)**  as column value and i obtain this result:

[image]

**Is there a method to apply these different colors only at "Type" and "Description" column and not to "State" column ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define just another [color definition column "use value as color"](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_WRITING_A_ROW_COLOR_FORMULA.html?lang=de) right after column "Description" and set color back to black `0:0:0`.

> The custom colors apply to the column containing the formula and all
>   columns that **follow**. Typically, the column containing the formula is
>   hidden.

Comment: I would reset to -1 : -1 : -1: That just "deletes" the color information, and all remaining columns will appear in the color they are designed in instead of all black...